# Get data attribute as object in Vue JS: returning [object object] even with JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, object

I'm trying to use Vue JS to achieve this: click a button with day name as the value, show shop open/close time. my idea is to attach the value in a `data-day` attribute, and assign the value to the div which displays the open/close time. I have the following code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="OpeningTimes">
        <input type="button" v-for="(value, key) in times" :value="key" :data-day="value" @click="showOpeningTimes">
        <div ref="info"></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="module">
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#OpeningTimes',
        data: {
            times: {
                'Monday': {
                    '09:00': 'open',  // Open
                    '12:20': 'closed', // Close for Lunch
                    '13:30': 'open',  // Return from Lunch
                    '17:00': 'closed' // Close for the day
                },

                'Tuesday': {
                    '09:00': 'open',  // Open
                    '12:20': 'closed', // Close for Lunch
                    '13:30': 'open',  // Return from Lunch
                    '17:00': 'closed' // Close for the day
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            showOpeningTimes: function (e) {
                this.$refs.info.innerText = e.target.dataset.day;
            }
        }
    })
</script>

</html>
```

It seems working cause I can see the `"key"` in the day object has been bound to the button value, but when I tried to access the `data-day` attribute in the method, it keeps giving me `[object object]`. I tried `JSON.stringify(e.target.dataset.day)`, still gave me "[object object]", how can I display the content in the object? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think using `key` to get `value` in your `showOpeningTimes` function would be a better aproach. Also you could pass `key` directly in `click` binding:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="OpeningTimes">
        <input type="button" v-for="(value, key) in times" :value="key" @click="showOpeningTimes(key)">
        <div ref="info"></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="module">
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#OpeningTimes',
        data: {
            times: {
                'Monday': {
                    '09:00': 'open',  // Open
                    '12:20': 'closed', // Close for Lunch
                    '13:30': 'open',  // Return from Lunch
                    '17:00': 'closed' // Close for the day
                },

                'Tuesday': {
                    '09:00': 'open',  // Open
                    '12:20': 'closed', // Close for Lunch
                    '13:30': 'open',  // Return from Lunch
                    '17:00': 'closed' // Close for the day
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            showOpeningTimes: function (key) {
                this.$refs.info.innerText = JSON.stringify(this.times[key]);
            }
        }
    })
</script>

</html>
```

As it was indicated in another answer, you can also pass `value` directly. It all depends on whether you need the `value` itself or the `key` you will need for something else in your function.

Comment: Thank you, new to Vue and did not know I could pass key value as a function parameter.